# Mac on Big Sur Eclipse problem with version.ini (Operation not permitted)

Tags: eclipse, version, macos-big-sur

After upgrading to Big Sur this weekend, my older version of Eclipse (Mars) I use for a specific project cannot be started.  I did the suggestion of updating the vm in `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Info.plist` -
[Not able to run Eclipse on macOS Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62647625/not-able-to-run-eclipse-on-macos-big-sur)

Now I am getting this error:

> !MESSAGE Could not read version file /Users/lorapowell/Documents/MARs
> workspace/.metadata/version.ini STACK 0 java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /Users/lorapowell/Documents/MARs workspace/.metadata/version.ini
> (Operation not permitted)

The file is there and has date (around when I did the upgrade?)

```
#Sat Jan 16 23:42:07 MST 2021
org.eclipse.core.runtime=2
org.eclipse.platform=4.5.2.v20160212-1500
```

My newer version of Eclipse is working fine.

Comment: I would suggest moving the workspace out of Documents - there seems to be even more protection on the Documents folder in macOS 11. But even then older versions of Eclipse tend to have UI rendering problems on Big Sur, fixes for these are only in Eclipse 2020-12

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to ensure you're running a more recent version of Eclipse than that.

The problem specifically shown here is because the Documents folder needs to be opted in to allow access from programs. This can be found in System Preferences, in the Security & Privacy preference pane on the Privacy tab.

You might find that Eclipse is showing in there with a Desktop folder without a checkmark. If that's the case, add the checkmark, then re-launch the application.

Comment: Actually the Desktop folder does have a checkmark

Comment: I suspect if you run it again then, it will work. However, the old version of Eclipse has other issues which means you would be well advised to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: This project uses cmvc, so I need to stay at an older version of Eclipse that allows me to set up a cmvc shared project (not just git).  Next problem is that it seems the libraries listed in the Build Path need to be in certain locations as well. Previous files located under my /Users/username/Downloads are not being found either.  Where is the right place for these files if Documents, Desktop and Downloads are all considered "special access"?  Library?  I don't seem to be able to create a new folder under my /Users/username folder now either...?

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Archive for required library: '/Users/lorapowell/Desktop/Nav4Liberty/auii18n.jar' in project '7.4f PDI' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file 7.4f PDI  Build path Build Path Problem

Answer (score 0):

After moving the zip files for the referenced build path libraries to under my /Users/profilename and re-expanding them, then updating the .classpath for these, cleaning and rebuilding as well as closing and reopening Eclipse a few times, I got things to sort themselves out. Build works.  Older eclipse, but it allows me to connect to my cmvc source project.