# OMNeT++ IDE on MacOS Sur

Tags: omnet++

I am using macOS Big Sur and OMNeT++ 5.6.2. I followed the instructions from the manual for the installation.

However, when typing `omnetpp` to start the IDE, I see the OMNeT++ icon showing up for only a split of a second. The `error.log` file says:

```
omnetpp[62922:141543] CheckForInstalledJavaRuntimes: Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing java.
```

Nevertheless, my java-version is:

```
% java -version
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)
```

I guess everything is fine so far, but I have no further idea to solve the error mentioned above and I am glad about hints. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [issue that comes from Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1104820&goto=1831020&#msg_1831020) and not directly from OMNeT++.

You first should make sure that you have Java installed (according to the issue mentioned in your `error.log` file).
[You could do that by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac/28635465#28635465):

```
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8
```

After you finished that, you may solve the issue by [adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62647625/not-able-to-run-eclipse-on-macos-big-sur)

```
<string>-vm</string><string>Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
```

to the `ide/omnetpp.app/Contents/Info.plist` file within your OMNeT++ 5.6.2 folder. The string should be added to the `array` element at the bottom of that file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but required an additional step. Here's the complete procedure.

**Step 1:** Install adoptopenjdk8

```
brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
```

**Step 2:** In file **ide/omnetpp.app/Contents/Info.plist**, insert the following between **array** tags

```
<array>
  ...
  <string>-vm</string>
  <string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
</array>
```

**Step 3:** Create a symbolic link to the JVM library

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libserver.dylib
```